# Objective C: Releasing a list, will it cause potential leaks?

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, release, nsdictionary, release-management

Tried finding the answer online, but couldn't. So i'm wondering if anyone else knows and why?

Say I have an `NSDictionary`, or `NSArray`, that stores objects inside of them. If I release the `NSDictionary`, is there a potential leak because I didn't release the objects inside of the `NSDictionary` list?

For example:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary alloc] init];
// Create a bunch of objects, NSStrings, etc.
// Store it into dict.
[dict release];
```

Will that also release everything inside of the dict? (objects, nsstrings, etc).
Thanks in advance people!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All items in an `NSDictionary` or `NSArray` are automatically retained when they're added and released when removed, or when the list is destroyed.

For example:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

MyObject *obj = [[MyObject alloc] init];
[dict setObject:obj forKey:@"foo"];  // the dictionary retains "obj"
[obj release];  // this matches the "alloc/init"
                // but "obj" still is retained by the dictionary

[dict release];  // now "obj" gets released
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do a release on a NSDictionary or NSArray, as long as the retain count of the objects inside the array is 1 (meaning as long as you released the objects after you inserted them inside the data structure), then once you release the dictionary or array, those objects will be released as well.